# Inherit function signature from another function

Tags: python, autocomplete, pycharm, autosuggest, method-signature

In `Python`, is it possible to define a function without explicitly specifying the input arguments/types/default values, and inherit the signature from another function?

The goal being to still get `PyCharm` to know the correct signature and auto-complete/suggest correctly.

Sample code:

```py
def generic_signature(arg1: bool = False, arg2: str = '42', arg3: dict = None, arg4: int = 42) -> dict[str, int]:
    pass

def my_function(...):  <--- Tell PyCharm to use the signature from generic_signature()
    pass
```

When I type `my_function(` in PyCharm, I want to see something like this:
[image: Expected PyCharm Output]

Comment: I don't believe so. While the type of the first function is the single "value" `Callable[[bool, str, dict, int], dict[str, int]]`, there is no way to *annotate* a function as a whole; you can only specify the types of the arguments and the return type separately.